# What approach to reading a panel of LEDs with machine vision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a panel of LEDs on my home heating system that I would like to monitor, non-invasively, using a web cam.

I can periodically take a photo of the LEDs and I would like to interpret the photos to determine which of my heating zones are active.

What software packages or solutions should I look at for identifying when each of the 6 LEDs is off or on? Ideally I would like to have some tolerance built in if the webcam were to move very slightly. Looking for packages with approachable documentation, or a tool that might help build a model.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBStx.jpg)

Comment: pick python over C++. the heavy lifting happens in the chosen library anyway. -- pick any image processing library. OpenCV might be helpful. scikit-image might be helpful. there are more. -- post a picture. -- you don't need AI. this sounds doable with very basic image processing.

Comment: assuming the camera can't move and neither can the LEDs, you could just take a picture, open in a photo editor, for every LED select a rectangle and write down the coordinates, and in code you can then just take the average of each region and compare against a threshold value.